# How can I access the $nev variable from a php code in a php code?

Tags: php

So, in the first php code I have a variable called $nev, which has a value from another php file by $_POST method.

```
<?php
  $nev = "'".$_POST['name']."'";
  echo $nev." stúdiumjainak megváltoztatása";
?>
```

Now I want to access it in valtoztatUpdate.php, but I can't do it. (I was trying to do it with keyword global but that was not working).

```
<?php
  //$nev = ?;
  $valt_hetfo = "'".$_POST['valt_hetfo']."'";
  $valt_kedd = "'".$_POST['valt_kedd']."'";
  $valt_szerda = "'".$_POST['valt_szerda']."'";
  $valt_csutortok = "'".$_POST['valt_csutortok']."'";
  @ $adatbazis = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'diakok');
    $adatbazis->set_charset('utf8');
    $sqlHetfo = "UPDATE diakok SET kot_hetfo=$valt_hetfo WHERE felhasznalonev=$nev";
    mysqli_query($adatbazis, $sqlHetfo);
    $sqlKedd = "UPDATE diakok SET kot_kedd=$valt_kedd WHERE felhasznalonev=$nev";
    mysqli_query($adatbazis, $sqlKedd);
    $sqlSzerda = "UPDATE diakok SET kot_szerda=$valt_szerda WHERE felhasznalonev=$nev";
    mysqli_query($adatbazis, $sqlSzerda);
    $sqlCsutortok = "UPDATE diakok SET kot_csutortok=$valt_csutortok WHERE felhasznalonev=$nev";
    mysqli_query($adatbazis, $sqlCsutortok);
?>
```

Comment: Where do you use valtoztatUpdate.php and first php file ?

Comment: Parameterize your queries. You can do the update with 1 query. Use commas for additional columns. Don't use the `@`, find out why you are getting an error and resolve it. If the connection fails it should be pretty obvious why this wouldn't work.

Comment: a session variable is probably the  easiest  option here

Comment: There is no problem with connecting to the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code.

First, to pass a variable from one PHP page to another, you'll either need to make use of a form submission, a **[session variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)** or **[AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started)**. Here's an example with a form submission:

```
<form action="valtoztatUpdate.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="nev" value="<?php echo $nev; ?>">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This creates a hidden field `nev` on your first page which will get `POST`ed to `valtoztatUpdate.php` upon a form submission, allowing you to access `$_POST['nev']` on `valtoztatUpdate.php`.

Second, you don't need to turn your `$_POST` into a string; it's already a string. However, you **will** want to make sure that the $_POST` is actually set:

```
if (isset($_POST['nev']) && $_POST['nev'] !== null) {
   ...
}
```

Third, you're vulnerable [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent this, making sure to bind your inputs to variables:

```
$stmt = $adatbazis->prepare('UPDATE diakok SET kot_hetfo = ? WHERE felhasznalonev = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $valt_hetfo, $nev); // 's' specifies the variable type => 'string'
$stmt->execute();
```

The above change to your `UPDATE` logic will make it so that people can't do nasty things like delete your entire database from simply changing what `$_POST['nev']` is.